# Wrong Khmer Unicode string

Tags: android, unicode, fonts, textview, android-typeface

[image]

I have problem with displaying Khmer Unicode in most of Android project. What I want to display is `អ៊ីមែល` but the result return with unexpected value.
I also try with custom font in Khmer and support encoding as `utf-8` but it still return the same result.

I'm not sure it is because of font or Android not support Khmer Unicode very well for now.

Any help anyone?

Comment: What is your API level and have you tried to change the encoding to UTF-16?

Comment: I think UTF-8 is correct and also it is not related to API level, because both compile time and run time it show the same result that I don't want as you can see screenshot above. Any more idea bro?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Likely link to font face that you are using, are you using. Here are some example, are you using Nokora, right?

[image]

And I could see also for Google web font, the written is the same:

[image]

So please check the correct font face before using, even in Noto google font face also, some are correct, some not correct too for that written.

Comment: ok thank you brother. But if all Khmer font should be correct all, because we not only use `Khmer OS Battambang` or `Daun Penh`. We need custom font style for sometime.

Comment: It not worked bro. I think it worked for you because you test it on other tools. In my IDE it worked fine too, but the problem is in design view or on run-time, it show incorrect result. Please test it with Android project bro to ensure.

Comment: Good. Yes, we should have one standard written font but someone need to pay to designer...

Comment: Well explanation :)